# Как с помощью hibernate получить список oracle object type

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

Всем привет.
В бд есть следующий тип:

```
create type p_records as object
(name varchar2(50),"sum" number,cur number);
```

и таблица которая его использует:

```
CREATE TABLE test_collections(
t_id NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
obj p_records,
PRIMARY KEY(t_id));
```

С помощью hibernate пытаюсь получить список всех объектов из этой таблице.

```
 Query query = session.createQuery("from Test_collections");
 List<Obj> objs = query.getResultList();
```

Но вместо списка получаю ошибку.

```
INFO: HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
Hibernate: select test_colle0_.t_id as t_id1_0_, test_colle0_.NAME as name2_0_, test_colle0_.sum as sum3_0_, test_colle0_.cur as cur4_0_ from test_collections test_colle0_
июн 08, 2022 1:29:52 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 904, SQLState: 42000
июн 08, 2022 1:29:52 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: ORA-00904: "TEST_COLLE0_"."CUR": недопустимый идентификатор
```

у меня не правильно строиться запрос. Не могу понять как это исправить.

Класс для типа p_records выглядит так:

```
    package types;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Obj implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private Integer sum;
    private Integer cur;

    public Obj(){};

    public Obj(String name,int sum,int cur){
      this.name = name;
      this.sum = sum;
      this.cur = cur;
    };

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getCur() {
        return cur;
    }

    public void setCur(Integer cur) {
        this.cur = cur;
    }

    public Integer getSum() {
        return sum;
    }

    public void setSum(Integer sum) {
        this.sum = sum;
    }
}
```

Класс который описывает тип:

```
    package types;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SharedSessionContractImplementor;
import org.hibernate.type.*;
import org.hibernate.usertype.CompositeUserType;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Types;
import java.util.Objects;

public class ObjType implements CompositeUserType
{

    @Override
    public String[] getPropertyNames() {
        return new String[]{"name","sum","cur"};
    }

    @Override
    public Type[] getPropertyTypes() {
        return new Type[]{StringType.INSTANCE, IntegerType.INSTANCE,IntegerType.INSTANCE};
        //return new Type[]{StandardBasicTypes.STRING,StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER,StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER};
    }

    @Override
    public Object getPropertyValue(Object o, int i) throws HibernateException {

        Obj obj = (Obj) o;

        switch (i){
            case 0:
                return obj.getName();
            case 1:
                return obj.getSum();
            case 2:
                return obj.getCur();
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException(o +
                " is an invalid property index for class type " +
                obj.getClass().getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void setPropertyValue(Object o, int i, Object o1) throws HibernateException {
        Obj obj = (Obj) o;

        switch (i){
            case 0:
                obj.setName((String) o1);
            case 1:
                obj.setSum((Integer) o1);
            case 2:
                obj.setCur((Integer) o1);

        throw new IllegalArgumentException(o + "is a invalid property for class type " +
                obj.getClass().getName());

        }
    }

    @Override
    public Class returnedClass() {
        return Obj.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o, Object o1) throws HibernateException {

        if(o == o1) return true;
        if(Objects.isNull(o) || Objects.isNull(o1)) return false;
        return o.equals(o1);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(Object o) throws HibernateException {
        return o.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet resultSet, String[] strings, SharedSessionContractImplementor sharedSessionContractImplementor, Object o) throws HibernateException, SQLException {

        if(resultSet.wasNull()) return null;

        Obj obj = new Obj();
        obj.setName(resultSet.getString(strings[0]));
        obj.setSum(resultSet.getInt(strings[1]));
        obj.setCur(resultSet.getInt(strings[2]));

        return obj;
    }

    @Override
    public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement preparedStatement, Object o, int i, SharedSessionContractImplementor sharedSessionContractImplementor) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        if(Objects.isNull(o)){
            preparedStatement.setNull(i, Types.VARCHAR);
        }else{
            Obj obj = (Obj) o;
            preparedStatement.setString(i,obj.getName());
            preparedStatement.setInt(i+1,obj.getSum());
            preparedStatement.setInt(i+2,obj.getCur());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object deepCopy(Object o) throws HibernateException {

        if(Objects.isNull(o)) return null;

        Obj obj = (Obj)o;
        Obj objForCopy = new Obj(obj.getName(),obj.getSum(), obj.getSum());

        return objForCopy;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMutable() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Serializable disassemble(Object o, SharedSessionContractImplementor sharedSessionContractImplementor) throws HibernateException {
        return (Serializable) deepCopy(o);
    }

    @Override
    public Object assemble(Serializable serializable, SharedSessionContractImplementor sharedSessionContractImplementor, Object o) throws HibernateException {
        return deepCopy(serializable);
    }

    @Override
    public Object replace(Object o, Object o1, SharedSessionContractImplementor sharedSessionContractImplementor, Object o2) throws HibernateException {
        return o;
    }
}
```

Описание таблицы:

```
package entities;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Columns;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef;
import org.hibernate.type.CompositeType;
import types.Obj;
import types.ObjType;

import javax.persistence.*;

//@TypeDef(name = "obj", typeClass = types.ObjType.class, defaultForType = Obj.class)

@Entity
@Table(name = "test_collections")
public class Test_collections {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "t_id")
    private Long t_id;



    @Columns(columns = { @Column(name = "NAME"),@Column(name = "sum"), @Column(name = "cur") })
    @Type(type = "types.ObjType")
    private Obj obj;

    public Test_collections() {
    };

    public Test_collections(Long t_id, Obj obj) {
        this.t_id = t_id;
        this.obj = obj;
    };

    public Long getT_id() {
        return t_id;
    }

    public void setT_id(Long t_id) {
        this.t_id = t_id;
    }

    public Obj getObj() {
        return obj;
    }

    public void setObj(Obj obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }
}
```

Полные исходники можно посмотреть тут https://github.com/developKmv/Hibernate_tst

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил, в итоги класс public class ObjType implements CompositeUserType мне не пригодился, просто изменил кдасс TestCollection:

```
package entities;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Columns;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef;
import org.hibernate.type.CompositeType;
import types.Obj;
import types.ObjType;

import javax.persistence.*;

//@TypeDef(name = "obj", typeClass = types.ObjType.class, defaultForType = Obj.class)

@Entity
@Table(name = "test_collections")
public class Test_collections {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "t_id")
    private Long t_id;

    @Column(name = "obj.name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "obj.\"sum\"")
    private Integer sum;
    @Column(name = "obj.cur")
    private Integer cur;

    /*@Columns(columns = { @Column(name = "NAME"),@Column(name = "sum"), @Column(name = "cur") })
    @Type(type = "types.ObjType")
    private Obj obj;*/

    public Test_collections() {
    };

    public Test_collections(Long t_id, String name, Integer sum, Integer cur) {
        this.t_id = t_id;
        this.name = name;
        this.sum = sum;
        this.cur = cur;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getSum() {
        return sum;
    }

    public void setSum(Integer sum) {
        this.sum = sum;
    }

    public Integer getCur() {
        return cur;
    }

    public void setCur(Integer cur) {
        this.cur = cur;
    }

    public Long getT_id() {
        return t_id;
    }

    public void setT_id(Long t_id) {
        this.t_id = t_id;
    }


}
```

В итоги запрос сформировался корректно

```
июн. 09, 2022 10:44:11 AM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
Hibernate: select test_colle0_.t_id as t_id1_0_, test_colle0_.obj.cur as obj2_0_, test_colle0_.obj.name as obj3_0_, test_colle0_.obj."sum" as obj4_0_ from test_collections test_colle0_
id: 1 name: mxv sum: 100 cur: 810
id: 2 name: grusha sum: 200 cur: 810
```